# Is there a term for a set of adjectives that describe intensity, weight, value, size, and so on?

Tags: semantics, grammar, adjectives

Some examples:

- **size:** micro, tiny, small, medium, large, huge, gigantic
- **temperature:** freezing, cold, chilly, cool, warm, hot
- **brightness:** dark, dim, light, bright
- **weight:** light, heavy

What are these sets of adjectives called?

The reason I'm asking is because I sometimes find myself needing these when I'm programming. A website with a database of whatever this is would be very helpful.

Comment: They are all adjectives. Is that what you are after?

Comment: @Peter Agreed. micro also has the status of a "metric prefix" with specific meaning. For examples: millisecond=one thousandth of a second; microsecond=one millionth of a second; kilogram = a thousand grams; megaton = a million tons.

Comment: It's describing something of intensity, value, temperature, size, etc with a set of adjectives. What is this set containing multiple adjectives called?

Comment: @Anton I think "metric prefix" is close, but it's very specific. We know that the gigabyte notation comes after the megabyte notation and we know exactly how much one megabyte is. 


My examples are more vague. We generally know that hot comes after warm, but we have no clear answer to what warm really is in Celsius or Fahrenheit.


I'm wondering what the term of this type of classification is called. I would think Metric is more about mathematics than language.

Comment: What about gradations. The word doesn't necessarily mean a set scale.

Comment: As you said yourself, all the adjectives you list are _descriptive_. They generally come after _opinion_ adjectives: _a lovely warm bath_, _a strange bright light_. etc.

Comment: @Peter After googling around for gradation I think I found it! "semantic gradient"

Comment: Are you asking about clines of gradability? Some adjectives reflect perceptual ranges: _boiling, hot, warm, tepid, cool, cold, freezing_. There is grammar associated with these clines, like comparatives, superlatives, and the use of _absolute(ly)_.